# Error in importing ArraySliceDep from dask.layers

Tags: dask

I got this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'ArraySliceDep' from 'dask.layers'
when I import stackstac. I have dask installed (2021.11.2 version) and my Python is 3.10 version

Comment: Please list the installed versions of all the relevant packages as given by pip, and how you installed everything.